# What is the "best practices" way to check if optional arguments are used in a function call in julia

Tags: julia

In python I might have a function like this:

```
def sum_these(x, y=None):
    if y is None:
        y = 1
    return x + y
```

What is the equivalent use in julia? To be exact I know I could probably do:

```
function sum_these(x, y=0)
    if y == 0
        y = 1
    end
    x + y
    end
```

However I'd rather not use zero, instead some value with the same meaning as `None` in python

**EDIT**

Just for clarity's sake, the result of these examples functions isn't important. The events(any) that happen if y is None are important, and for my cases setting y=[some number] is undesirable. After some search I think, unless someone provides a better solution is to do something like:

```
function sum_these(x, y=nothing)
    if y == nothing
        do stuff
    end
    return something
```

Comment: maybe this isn't suitable for your use case but often you don't need to do this and you can just set the default as `1` or some function of the arguments instead.

Comment: Your use case is a bit mysterious, so it's hard to be helpful. One alternative, though, is to define two separate methods, `sum_these(x)` and `sum_these(x, y)`, and perhaps let one call the other. If you provide more detail, it will be much easier to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function sum_these(x, y=nothing)
  if y == nothing
    do stuff
  end
  return something 
end
```

That's not only perfectly fine, but because `nothing` is a singleton of type `Void`, the `y==nothing` will actually compile away so the if statement is actually no runtime cost here. I talk about this in depth [in a blog post](http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/type-dispatch-design-post-object-oriented-programming-julia/), but what it really means is that function auto-specialization allows for checks against nothing to always be free in type-stable/inferrable functions.

However, you may want to consider splitting this into two different functions:

```
function sum_these(x)
  return something 
end 

function sum_these(x, y)
  do stuff
  return something 
end
```

Of course, this is just a style difference and the right choice is determined by how much code is shared in the `return something`.

Comment: The question was about 'best practices', though, and in that case, I _suspect_ that the `y=nothing` version is not quite it. My impression is that it's a roundabout way to take care of the situation where there is only one input, and doing it the 'Python way' instead of just explicitly using multiple dispatch. What if two inputs _are_ provided, but the second one is `nothing`? Then it gets treated the same as the single argument method, but perhaps it should be an error instead.

As a matter of style, I think splitting into two methods is better.

Comment: But it isn't always better. If there would be a lot of repeated code, it can be better to just put them together. Or maybe have an internal function `_do_something(...)` for the `return something` part if you do split the functions. As always, it depends on the circumstance. However, it's an important fact that compiler optimizations on singletons leads to both forms being just as optimal.

Comment: Yes, there is no clear-cut answer to this question, since there is so little detail, and my suggestion is _not_ always better. But I was therefore trying to make a guess as to the intentions of the OP, and my guess was that the core of the question was how to create functions that could have either one or two inputs. The default answer is then, I believe, to use two different methods, but that depends indeed on other circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use multiple dispatch with an empty fallback?

```
function f(x, y=nothing)
    ...
    do_something(x, y)
    ...
    return something
end

do_something(x, y) = nothing
function do_something(x, y::Void)
    ...
end
```

add other relevant vars to `do_something` as necessary, and return something or mutate as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing. It seems like what you want is

```
function sum_these(x, y=1)
    return x + y
end
```

But that doesn't quite do what you are asking either, since even if you call `sum_these(3, 0)` in your example, it replaces 0 with 1.

Also in Python, I would use

```
def sum_these(x, y=1):
    return x + y
```

Perhaps I misunderstand your question.